# If there are m items of one kind,n items of another kind and so on, then the number of ways of choosing r items of these items is

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

Please prove this result:

> If there are m items of one kind,n items of another kind and so on, then the number of ways of choosing r items of these items is

=Coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^m)$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)$$...$

> If there are $m$ items of one kind,$n$ items of another kind and so on, then the number of ways of choosing $r$ items of these items such that at least one item of each kind is included in every $s$
>   selection is:

=Coefficient of $x^r$ in $(x+x^2+...+x^m)$$(x+x^2+...+x^n)$$...$

In my textbook only this result is given but not the proof.Maybe because **Binomial Theorem** is our chapter next to **Permutations**.
But I want to know this proof because I am not able to memorize math results or formulae without knowing it's proof.Please help!!!

My attempt: I have no clue about **Binomial Chapter** I just know basic results and formulae.That's why I can't move even a step.Please don't close my question.

Answer (score 1):

I will not prove it, but I will try to give you some intuition about what's going on. Let me simplify the first formula into

$$(\textrm{# of 1st items})\cdot(\textrm{# of 2nd items})\cdot\dots\cdot(\textrm{# of last items})$$

Say there are $n$ different kinds in total. Imagine each "$(\textrm{# of _ items})$" as a panel, once you decide how much amount you want for that kind, you press a button on that panel. (here "press" a button is analogy for choosing a term in the parenthesis/panel) Say you want $k$ copies of that kind, then you press the button $x^k$. (and for some kind(s) you don't want any, press $x^0=1$.) So in your second formula those "$1$"(, which actually means $x^0$) buttons are missing so you have to choose at least one for each kind (so sad.) This mechanism includes all the possibility.

---

The details behind this are two simple(but important) ideas of combinatorics, and an algebra rule you must be familiar with:

- Product rule: Once you press any button, you just decide the amount for that kind, no effect to any other panels.
- Distribution law: Notice that all coefficients of $x^k$ are $1$'s, so once you "expand" the formula each term still has $1$ as its coefficient. This is good because each round of $n$-decisions represent one way of choosing. (and these ways are also mutually independent!)

Assume you have expanded the formula, and for each term notice that $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$, let us just focus on the exponent part, it's actually count the total items you got "in this way", regardless of which kind(s) of item you've chosen. Finally, the rule I like the most

- Addition rule: Now all terms with the same "label" $x^k$ are simply summed up, since all "ways" are mutually independent(no need to subtract the repetition(s)), the coefficient of $x^k$ means: How many possible "ways" that end up with $k$ items chosen out.

And I left the formal proof for your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the product $(1+ax+a^2x^2+...+a^mx^m)(1+bx+b^2x^2+...+b^nx^n)\ldots\ $ results in a sum of $(m+1)(n+1)\ldots\ $ terms of the type $a^kb^l\ldots\ x^r$ with $k+l+\ldots=r$.

For a fixed $r$ the coefficients of the $x^r$-terms correspond with the ways of choosing $k$ items of the first kind plus $l$ items of the second kind plus $\ldots$ etcetera for a total of $r$ items.

Setting $a=b=\ldots=1$ gives all these coefficients the value $1$ and the $x^r$-terms can be combined into $c_rx^r$, where $c_r$ is the number of different selections for $r$ items.