# Understanding methods to solve combination problems involving more than one type of identical objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the total number of ways of selecting $6$ balls out of $20$ red balls, $10$ blue balls, and $7$ black balls

This is solved in my reference as
$$
\text{coeff. of }x^6 \text{ in }(1+x+x^2+...+x^{20})(1+x+x^2+...+x^{10})(1+x+x^2+...+x^7)=28
$$

I think it makes use of the following equation

> If there are $m$ items of one kind, $n$ items of another kind and so on, then the number of ways of choosing $r$ items of these items is
>
> =Coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^m)(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)...$

A decent attempt to explain this is done at [If there are m items of one kind,n items of another kind and so on, then the number of ways of choosing r items of these items is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916961/if-there-are-m-items-of-one-kind-n-items-of-another-kind-and-so-on-then-the-num), by @Postal Model, which is not a proof but rather a rough attempt to provide an intuition, if I can call that. I have done a bit googling, in most of the books this formula is given just like that without any proof nor any explanation into how such a formula can give what it is said it gives.

So how can I attempt to solve such problems without actually making use of such a given formula ?

Comment: "how can I attempt to solve such problems without actually making use of such a given formula?" Well, for one thing, you could try to *understand* the formula, then you'd feel better about using it. So, do you want an explanation of the formula, or would you rather have some other method entirely?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Either a proper explanation on how such a formula is formed or may be some other step by step way if there is another way to approach such problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just changed the title, may be it was bit misleading before.

Comment: You can get the proper spacing for the ellipsis by using `\ldots` instead of three periods. Also, with binary operators like $+$, it looks better when you use vertically centred dots with `\cdots` instead of dots on the baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t like the generating function method, you can always use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): You have $6$ slots, and you add $2$ separators between the $3$ sections of slots for the $3$ colours, so there are $\binom{6+2}2=28$ ways to do that. Of course that only works because you have enough balls of each colour to fill all the slots; for the case where you don’t, see e.g. [In how many different ways can apples be placed in the box if at least there is one apple of each color?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530271/)

Comment: I am familiar with stars and bars approach, for example, identical objects with distinct groups with empty groups allowed, there are total $n+r-1$ positions for $r-1$ bars to occupy, thus ${}^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$,and for with no empty groups allowed, there are $n-1$ positions for $r-1$ bars to occupy thus ${}^{n-1}C_{r-1}$. Have no clue how to apply that here.

Comment: @ss1729: But that's exactly what you want to do here, distributing identical objects over distinct groups with empty groups allowed. There are $n=6$ balls to choose, and you want to distribute those choices over $r=3$ colours.

Comment: ohh thanks, I didn't think that way, identical objects are the $n=6$ slots and $r=3$ groups represent each colors, and ie., $n+r-1=8$ and $r-1=2$, right ? btw why on earth we are using such a cumbersome formula for such cases, which is what is given in many books, when we have this simple approach.

Comment: @ss1729: Right. The generating function approach is indeed overkill for the present case, but if you look at the question I linked to, where there aren't enough balls/apples of each colour to fill all the slots, it's not that much more complicated than the inclusion–exclusion approach, especially considering that in that case I only had to write the first-order inclusion–exclusion terms whereas if you could run out of more than one colour at a time the inclusion–exclusion sum would also become more complicated, whereas the generating function stays the same.

Comment: why is it not ${}^{n-1}C_{r-1}={}^{9-1}C_{3-1}={}^{8}C_{2}=28$, as there must be atleast one apple of each color,  ie., no empty group allowed, in the problem you have mentioned ?

Comment: @ss1729: Because there is only a limited supply of apples of each colour. In your case, you have enough balls of each colour to have any combination of colours (including having all balls of the same colour), whereas in that other problem there are e.g. not enough red apples to have a selection of only red apples.

Comment: There are $9$ slots but only $4$ red, $5$ green, $6$ yellow, it should be ${}^{9-1}C_{3-1}-$[#{more than 4 red}+#{more than 5 green}+#{more than 6 yellow}]$={}^{8}C_{2}-[{}^{4}C_{2}+{}^{3}C_{2}+{}^{2}C_{2}]$. And #{more than 4 red} is found by taking, 4 slots in red group is taken, remaining 5 slots are partitioned into 3 groups with no empty groups allowed, similar for other cases too, right ?

Comment: So for record, do I really need the generating function approach for any of such problems, if I can think like this using inclusion-exclusion principle ?

Comment: @ss1729: On the first of your last two comments: Yes you can do it that way, that's a bit more direct than the approach the OP took in that post – they distributed one apple to each colour and then distributed the rest with empty groups allowed. The result is of course the same. On your last comment: No, you don't need the generating function approach here if you prefer to use inclusion–exclusion. It's usually the case that things you can do with generating functions can also be done in other ways. Sometimes one approach seems more natural or straightforward, sometimes another.